# How can I reset the global variable after calling the function?

Tags: javascript, recursion, global-variables

I've written a function with recursive approach to get the values from nested Array.
The problem is, I can't reset the global variable after each call. Here after every call the results are being appended to previous result instead of giving new result. I know, Global variable isn't being reset, so data will always append. But I can't define the variable inside the function as its recursive call.

How can I avoid this situation? Any help would be appreciated.

```
var res = [];
function getData(arr) {
  if(!Array.isArray(arr)) {
    res.push(arr);
    return res;
  }
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    getData(arr[i]);
  }
  return res;
}

getData([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]]); // res = [1, 2, 3, 4]
getData([[["a"]], [["b"]]]);   // res = [1, 2, 3, 4, "a", "b"], expected is res = ["a", "b"];
getData([1, {}, [3, [[4]]]]);
```

Comment: Simply make the result array a parameter of the function? `function getData(arr, res) { ... }` and `getData([...], [])`.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks..its an fine approach, but I don't have to pass an extra parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I can't define the variable inside the function as its recursive
>   call.

You can define the result variable inside the function but you need to properly deal with the return values of your recursive calls:

```
function getData(arr) {
    var res = [];

    if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            res = res.concat(getData(arr[i]));
        }
    } else {
        res.push(arr);
    }

    return res;
}
```

(And you don't need to make the result array a parameter of the function.)

Answer (score 0):

Landed up with another solution using closure, it might help someone.

```
function getData(arr) {
  var res = [];
  return innerGetData(arr);

  function innerGetData(arr) {
    if(!Array.isArray(arr)) {
      res.push(arr);
      return res;
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      innerGetData(arr[i]);
    }
    return res;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey a variant of the solution above is:

```js
function steamrollArray(arr) {
    var newArr = [];
    arr.forEach(function(el){
      if(!Array.isArray(el)){
          newArr.push(el);
      } else {
        newArr = newArr.concat(steamrollArray(el));
      }
   });

   return newArr;
}
```

:)

Answer (score -1):

Use pop(array_name) to remove the last item from the array after you're done with it.

-- Ada